# Should the join between door frame & brick be sealed

Tags: doors, sealing

This uPVC door has recently been installed, but there's a noticeable gap between the frame and the surrounding brick when viewed from outside. A sealant of some sort was applied during installation to prevent water reaching the building interior, but does there need to be sealant, caulking or similar on the exterior?

[image: exterior view of door frame with gap between plastic & brickwork]

Comment: Do you get temperatures cold enough to freeze water?

Comment: Yes, I'm in the UK

Comment: I would seal the outside.  Frozen water does nasty things to pipes/tight spaces like cracks in hard rocks.

Comment: Did they apply [compriband](https://www.bricozor.com/compriband-adhesif-trsaa-pc-tramico.html?ref=589953)? It's an adhesive foam joint that comes in roll form, you apply it on the sides of the door frame and install the door, then over a few hours it will slowly expand and seal the crack. It's very convenient and unlike spray foam, doesn't make a mess. You can check by shining a light in the crack, do you see black foam?

Comment: I'll check once I'm back home @bobflux

Comment: Here is an English link to describe the [Compriband tape](https://www.dortechdirect.co.uk/blog/what-is-compriband-tape-and-who-should-use-it/) mentioned by @bobflux. Sounds pretty handy, therefore it's probably not available in the US. :(

Comment: @Freeman it's great for wide/uneven spaces because it expands, but it does so very slowly and can be compressed again. So it can also be used for "unofficial" applications like the attic trapdoor, or old doors that don't close properly. It doesn't have time to expand when opening and closing the door so it makes a nice seal without having to press heavily on the door to close it...

Comment: Oh, great, thanks, @bobflux. Give me even more reasons to want something I can't have. Sigh...

Comment: @FreeMan try searching for "expansion foam joint" or "expanding foam joint" https://portlandstoneware.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/FND_Installation-Guide-2022.pdf

Comment: There's no adhesive foam in the gap, but I can see sillicone sealant a couple of cm in there